# Largest singular value in geometry (3D line fitting)

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation, interpolation

I have a question about 3D line fitting algorithm as described here: 
https://www.codefull.net/2015/06/3d-line-fitting/

Please tell me, is the largest singular value somehow related to length of the line segment on the plot?
Can I use it as $t_\max$ in parametric equation $P = p_0 + t\cdot d$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.